# Flutter create scrollable from widget built manual and generated textform builds inside listview on a dialog

Tags: flutter, dart, web, bloc

hi im trying to create a scrollable form with text form field widgets and inside the form will be a list view of widgets all this should be displayed on a dialog. This is my code for the form itself not the dialog.

```
import 'dart:developer' as dev;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:track/src/features/invoices/model/invoice.dart';

import 'package:track/src/features/invoices/application/pdf_invoice_api.dart';

class InvoiceForm extends StatefulWidget {
  Invoice invoice;

  InvoiceForm({Key? key, required this.invoice}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InvoiceForm> createState() => _InvoiceFormState();
}

class _InvoiceFormState extends State<InvoiceForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: TextEditingController()..text = widget.invoice.client,
              validator: (value) {
                value!.isEmpty ? 'Enter a value for client' : null;
              },
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Client:',
                  labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.invoice.items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final item = widget.invoice.items[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            itemTextFormField(
                              initialValue: item.name,
                              labelText: 'Name',
                              index: index,
                            ),
                            itemTextFormField(
                              initialValue: item.description,
                              index: index,
                              labelText: 'description',
                            ),
                            itemTextFormField(
                                initialValue: item.quantity.toString(),
                                index: index,
                                labelText: 'quantity'),
                            itemTextFormField(
                                initialValue: item.costBeforeVAT.toString(),
                                index: index,
                                labelText: 'Before VAT'),
                          ]),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      _formKey.currentState!.save();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      await PdfInvoiceApi.generate(widget.invoice);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget itemTextFormField({
    required String initialValue,
    required String labelText,
    required int index,
  }) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: TextEditingController()..text = initialValue,
      onSaved: (newValue) {
        if (newValue!.isNotEmpty) {
          switch (labelText) {
            case 'Name':
              widget.invoice.items[index].name = newValue;
              break;
            case 'Description':
              widget.invoice.items[index].description = newValue;
              break;
            case 'Quantity':
              widget.invoice.items[index].quantity = int.parse(newValue);
              break;
            case 'Before VAT':
              widget.invoice.items[index].quantity = int.parse(newValue);
          }
        }
      },
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        labelText: 'Item:',
        labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is error I am recieving:

```
======= Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Assertion failed: file:///home/ranvir/.local/share/ProgrammingFrameworks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:2009:12
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderMouseRegion#86185 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE"

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView SingleChildScrollView:file:///home/ranvir/AndroidStudioProjects/track/lib/src/features/invoices/presentation/invoice_dialog_form.dart:22:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3        assertFailed
performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart 56:10                           layoutChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart 903:45                                   [_computeSizes]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart 938:32                                   performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 240:5                             performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 297:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart 552:11                           performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 1467:11                             performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 297:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 442:7                             performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 240:5                             performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 240:5                             performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 240:5                             performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 3815:13                             performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart 852:14                                  performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2007:7                                 [_layoutWithoutResize]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1020:17                                flushLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 516:19                                drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 869:13                                  drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 381:5                                 [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1275:15                               [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1204:9                                handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1062:5                                [_handleDrawFrame]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1168:13                               invoke
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 218:5                                 invokeOnDrawFrame
lib/_engine/engine/initialization.dart 186:45                                     <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 352:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 357:39  dcall
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPointerListener#f8e6f relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  behavior: deferToChild
...  listeners: down, panZoomStart
RenderObject: RenderPointerListener#f8e6f relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  behavior: deferToChild
  listeners: down, panZoomStart
...  child: RenderMouseRegion#86185 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: <none> (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: MISSING
...    behavior: opaque
...    listeners: hover, exit
...    child: RenderCustomPaint#d0e0e relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      size: MISSING
...      painter: null
...      foregroundPainter: ScrollbarPainter#d9c98
...      child: RenderRepaintBoundary#db202 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: MISSING
...        usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...        child: _RenderScrollSemantics#773d3 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          semantic boundary
...          size: MISSING
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Assertion failed: file:///home/ranvir/.local/share/ProgrammingFrameworks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:2009:12
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#f8e6f relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE"

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView SingleChildScrollView:file:///home/ranvir/AndroidStudioProjects/track/lib/src/features/invoices/presentation/invoice_dialog_form.dart:22:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3        assertFailed
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2009:12                                   get size
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 121:14                              performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 2169:7                                 layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2430:11                                   layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 120:7                               performLayout
 invokeOnDrawFrame
lib/_engine/engine/initialization.dart 186:45                                     <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 352:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 357:39  dcall
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#7dc89 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  behavior: deferToChild
...  gestures: <none>
RenderObject: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#7dc89 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  behavior: deferToChild
  gestures: <none>
...  child: RenderPointerListener#f8e6f relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: <none> (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: MISSING
...    behavior: deferToChild
...    listeners: down, panZoomStart
...    child: RenderMouseRegion#86185 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      size: MISSING
...      behavior: opaque
...      listeners: hover, exit
...      child: RenderCustomPaint#d0e0e relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: MISSING
...        painter: null
...        foregroundPainter: ScrollbarPainter#d9c98
...        child: RenderRepaintBoundary#db202 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=810.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          size: MISSING
...          usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
====================================================================================================
```

I can get it to display without the listveiw builder but ofc I need that, so user can add delete a set of form fields at same time. So is there a solution?

Edit 2:
After removing the Exapanded widget and applying shrink wrap I got this:
[image: Dialog Form Error]

But replacing form fields with text widgets works:
[image: Dialog From Text Widget replaced form fields]

```dart
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.invoice.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = widget.invoice.items[index];
                return ListTile(title: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(item.name),
                      SizedBox(width: 10,), Text(item.description),
                      // SizedBox(height: 20),
                      // itemTextFormField(
                      //   initialValue: item.name,
                      //   labelText: 'Name', index: index,),
                      // itemTextFormField(
                      //   initialValue: item.description, index: index, labelText: 'description',
                      // ),
                      // itemTextFormField(
                      //     initialValue: item.quantity.toString(),
                      //     index: index, labelText: 'quantity'),
                      // itemTextFormField(
                      //     initialValue: item.costBeforeVAT.toString(),
                      //     index: index, labelText: 'Before VAT'),
                    ],),);},),
```

Edit 3: Tearing down the code a bit more showed that I could have the text form fields inside the title. The problem comes with inserting the row widget.

```
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: widget.invoice.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = widget.invoice.items[index];
                return ListTile(
                    title: itemTextFormField(
                        initialValue: item.name,
                        labelText: 'name',
                        index: index));
              },
            ),
```

This works but is not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Expanded` in the `SingleChildScrollView` or other scrollable widgets, so remove the `Expanded` Widget and use `shrinkWrap: true` for your `ListView.builder` like this:

```
class InvoiceForm extends StatefulWidget {
  Invoice invoice;

  InvoiceForm({Key? key, required this.invoice}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InvoiceForm> createState() => _InvoiceFormState();
}

class _InvoiceFormState extends State<InvoiceForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: TextEditingController()..text = widget.invoice.client,
              validator: (value) {
                value!.isEmpty ? 'Enter a value for client' : null;
              },
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Client:',
                  labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: widget.invoice.items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final item = widget.invoice.items[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Expanded(
                            child: itemTextFormField(
                              initialValue: item.name,
                              labelText: 'Name',
                              index: index,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: itemTextFormField(
                              initialValue: item.description,
                              index: index,
                              labelText: 'description',
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: itemTextFormField(
                              initialValue: item.quantity.toString(),
                              index: index,
                              labelText: 'quantity',
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: itemTextFormField(
                              initialValue: item.costBeforeVAT.toString(),
                              index: index,
                              labelText: 'Before VAT',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  );
                }),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      _formKey.currentState!.save();
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      await PdfInvoiceApi.generate(widget.invoice);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget itemTextFormField({
    required String initialValue,
    required String labelText,
    required int index,
  }) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: TextEditingController()..text = initialValue,
      onSaved: (newValue) {
        if (newValue!.isNotEmpty) {
          switch (labelText) {
            case 'Name':
              widget.invoice.items[index].name = newValue;
              break;
            case 'Description':
              widget.invoice.items[index].description = newValue;
              break;
            case 'Quantity':
              widget.invoice.items[index].quantity = int.parse(newValue);
              break;
            case 'Before VAT':
              widget.invoice.items[index].quantity = int.parse(newValue);
          }
        }
      },
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        labelText: 'Item:',
        labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you need to put your itemTextFormField in an Expanded widget when you use this in a row:

```
                      Expanded(
                        child: itemTextFormField(
                          initialValue: item.name,
                          labelText: 'Name',
                          index: index,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: itemTextFormField(
                          initialValue: item.description,
                          index: index,
                          labelText: 'description',
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: itemTextFormField(
                          initialValue: item.quantity.toString(),
                          index: index,
                          labelText: 'quantity',
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: itemTextFormField(
                          initialValue: item.costBeforeVAT.toString(),
                          index: index,
                          labelText: 'Before VAT',
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: so I made the changes to the code but I am still getting errors. Then I replaced the text fields with text widgets and now its working all fine. The dialog screen the form being posted in now white. I'll update my question to show the results.

Comment: Please review the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update i did find the answer to this already but as the answer you typed out was the solution, ill mark it down as the answer. If you could I have another question stack overflow to do with form, if you could take a look that would be great: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249808/good-way-to-mange-state-inside-dialog-with-a-form-on-it-being-displayed-from-pa